# Help understand this gcd proof for $gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, a) = gcd(±a, ±b) = gcd(a, b − a) = gcd(a, b + a)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

From:
Elementary Number Theory:
Primes, Congruences, and Secrets
by William Stein

${Lemma}$ $1.1.9.$ For any integers a and b, we have
gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, a) = gcd(±a, ±b) = gcd(a, b − a) = gcd(a, b + a).

$Proof.$ We only prove that $gcd(a, b) = gcd(a, b − a)$, since the other cases
are proved in a similar way. Suppose $d | a$ and $d | b$, so there exist integers
$c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $dc_1 = a$ and $dc_2 = b$. Then $b−a = d(c_2−c_1)$, so $d | b − a$. Thus $gcd(a, b) ≤ gcd(a, b − a)$, since the set over which we are
taking the max for $gcd(a, b)$ is a subset of the set for $gcd(a, b − a)$. The
same argument with a replaced by $−a$ and $b$ replaced by $b − a$, shows that
$gcd(a, b − a) = gcd(−a, b − a) ≤ gcd(−a, b) = gcd(a, b),$ which proves that
$gcd(a, b) = gcd(a, b − a)$.

I don't understand how they came to this conclusion:

> Thus $gcd(a, b) ≤ gcd(a, b − a)$, since the set over which we are taking
>   the max for $gcd(a, b)$ is a subset of the set for $gcd(a,b-a)$.

Comment: Since  $\gcd(a,b)$ divides both $a$ and $b-a$  it is clear that $\gcd(a,b)≤\gcd(a, b-a)$  (any common divisor is $≤$ the gcd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that if any number $d$ divides $a,b$ (and hence $(a,b)$ then it also divides $(a,b-a)$. So all the divisors of $(a,b)$ ultimately lie in the set of divisors of $(a,b-a)$ and hence (set of all divisors of $(a,b)$ is a subset of $(a,b-a)$)

Now notice that $(a,b)$ and $(a,b-a)$ are highest numbers in the respective sets. Thus $(a,b)\le (a,b-a) $

Here $(a,b)=GCD(a,b)$